# Full text search: in any array item find node value

Tags: postgresql

json

```
{
    "availability": [{
            "qty": 25,
            "price": 28990,
            "is_available": true
        },
        {
            "qty": 72,
            "price": 28990,
            "is_available": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Full text search to find value or node **price = 28990** in first array item I use this:

```
select * 
from product 
where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{availability, 0, price}') @@ to_tsquery('28990')
```

Nice.

But I need to find not only it in the first array's item. I need to find it in all items in array.
Smt like this (pseudo code):

```
  select * 
    from product 
    where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{availability, ... , price}') @@ to_tsquery('28990')
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Full text search is the wrong tool for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the containment operator `@>`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
WHERE product.data @> '{"availability": [ { "price": 28990 } ] }';
```